# Querying Different Table If First Result is Empty

Tags: sql

I'm writing a stored procedure to look in two tables PersonTbl, UserTbl. First search the PersonTbl for an userID and if the userID is there get an email address from the UserTbl and return both. However if the ID is not there then search two other tables (PersonsPendingTbl, UsersPendingTbl) for the ID and email. If the ID is not found once again, return null/nulls. So far this is what I've come up with, but not sure if it's the best way of writing it. Let me know if there's any changes you would recommend;

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyNewSP]
@ID VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
    DECLARE @userID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @currentlyActive CHAR
    BEGIN

    SELECT
        @userID = userTbl.ID ,
        @Email = personTbl.EMAIL,
        @currentlyActive = 'Y'
    FROM
        personTbl
        INNER JOIN userTbl ON personTbl.person_id = userTbl.person_id
    WHERE
        ( userTbl.ID = @ID )


    IF ( @userID != @ID ) --Check to see if null
        BEGIN
            SELECT @currentlyActive = 'N'

            SELECT
                upt.ID ,
                ppt.EMAIL,
                @currentlyActive
            FROM
                PersonsPendingTbl ppt
                INNER JOIN dbo.UsersPendingTbl upt ON ppt.person_id = upt.person_id
            WHERE
                ( upt.ID = @ID )
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                @userID ,
                @Email ,
                @currentlyActive
        END

END
```

Comment: The `CREATE PROCEDURE` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a union of both results, but always pick the first row. If the user is registered as Active AND Inactive, it'll return the Active one:

```
Select * 
  from (
    SELECT userTbl.ID AS UID, personTbl.EMAIL as email, 'Y' as active
      FROM personTbl
        JOIN userTbl ON personTbl.person_id = userTbl.person_id
        WHERE (userTbl.ID = @ID)
    union all
    SELECT upt.ID AS UID, ppt.EMAIL as email, 'N' as active
      FROM PersonsPendingTbl ppt
        INNER JOIN dbo.UsersPendingTbl upt ON ppt.person_id = upt.person_id
      WHERE (upt.ID = @ID)) user
  limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about uniqueness of values between your pending and non-pending table, but this should be close enough to get you going.

```
select 
case 
    when p.PersonId is null and pp.personPendingId is null then null 
    else userid
end as userid,
case 
    when p.PersonId is not null  then p.email
    when p.PersonId is null and pp.PersonPendingID is not null then pp.email
    else null
end as email,
case 
    when p.PersonId is not null  then 'Y' 
    when p.PersonId is null and pp.PersonPendingID is not null then 'N' 
    else null
end as CurrentlyActive
from userTbl u 
left join PersonTbl p on u.Person_id = p.PersonId 
left join userPendingTbl up on u.UserId = up.UserPendingId 
left join PersonPendingTbl pp on up.personPendingId = pp.PersonPendingID 
where u.UserId = @ID
```